# Copy multiple csv files to multiple sheets of an excel using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to copy my CSV files test1.csv and test2.csv to a single excel workbook in multiple sheets means sheet1 should have data from test1.csv and sheet2 data should have data from test2.csv.

As excel is not supported as sink so I am not able to do this . Also if I am going through binary option then I am not able to use sheet option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Excel as a Sink functionality is yet not available in ADF.
And Binary dataset is used when you want to move a file as is without changing its properties  (you cannot use it for file changes)

In order for you to achieve your use case, you would have to write your won custom logic via databricks, batch ,Azure function etc